# Properties of matrices using Gershgorin circles

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, gershgorin-sets

We have the matrix \begin{equation*}A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2/3 & -4/3 \\2/3 & -2/3 & 2 \\ -4/3 & 2 & -1/3\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

We have the Gershorin circles :
\begin{align*}&K_1=\left \{\left |x-1\right |\leq \left |\frac{2}{3}\right |+\left |-\frac{4}{3}\right |\right \}=\left \{\left |x-1\right |\leq 2\right \} \\ 
&K_2=\left \{\left |x+\frac{2}{3}\right |\leq \left |\frac{2}{3}\right |+\left |2\right |\right \}=\left \{\left |x+\frac{2}{3}\right |\leq \frac{8}{3}\right \} \\ 
&K_3=\left \{\left |x+\frac{1}{3}\right |\leq \left |-\frac{4}{3}\right |+\left |2\right |\right \}=\left \{\left |x+\frac{1}{3}\right |\leq \frac{10}{3}\right \}\end{align*}
right?

We have three questions that we should answer using these circles and the structure of the matrix.

(a) Is it possible that $A$ is singular?

(b) Is it possible that the matrix has also complex eigenvalues?

(c) Is it possible that the matrix $A$ is negatively/positively definite/semidefinite or indefinite?

$$$$

I have done the following :

(a) The matrix is not strictly diagonally dominant, so the matrix is singular.

The Gerschgorin circles intersect the origin, so that the matrix is singular.

Is that correct?

(b) Do we have complex eigenvalues if two Gershgorin circles intersect?

Comment: (a) wrong. strictly dominant implies regular, but non strictly dominant does *not* imply singular. Take $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for instance. And the eigenvalues are in the union of Gershgorin disks, that says nothing more about their actual value. (b) Why would this be true? You should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem.

Comment: Taking only the information given by Gershgorin disks into account: (a) True because $0$ lies in at least one of the disks. (b) True as there are complex conjugate values in the disks (it's always the case for a real matrix, as the centers are on the real line), but note the matrix is symmetric, so has real eigenvalues. (c) True as there are positive and negative values in the discs. And note that the diagonal has positive and negative values, then compute $e_i^TAe_i$.

Comment: So at (c) we concluse that the matrix must be indefinite, right? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: From the Gershgorin disks only, you can't conclude, it can be anything. But given that there are positive and negative numbers on the diagonal, it's indefinite (because it's easy to find vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $x^TAx>0$ and $y^TAy<0$).

Comment: The Gershgorin circles in this problem aren't very interesting are they? We can't really draw sharp conclusions from them because they are so large.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much !! :-)